# Custom UI for UWP Background Media Playback

Tags: c#, uwp, mediaplayback

My test app tries to play audio when minimising app, so I selected "Background Media Playback". But when I move my mouse over the App Icon on the Windows Taskbar, Next/Prev/Pause buttons are displayed (see below image). How can I remove them?

[image: Image showing popup window from app taskbar button, with 'previous', 'pause' and 'next' buttons. Also shown is a window with check boxes under the heading 'Capabilities'. The 'background media playback' button is ticked]

Comment: have u fixed it? I also encount this problem and i try the answer below but it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable them from the Background task using the `IsEnabled` property of the [SystemMediaTransportControls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.systemmediatransportcontrols) class.

```
var controls = BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.SystemMediaTransportControls;
controls.IsEnabled = false;
```

Similarly, you can disable them when the app is in the foreground using:

```
var controls = SystemMediaTransportControls.GetForCurrentView();
controls.IsEnabled = false;
```