# how to remove thumbnail toolbar in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, background, mediaplayback, thumbnail-toolbar

I enable backgroundMediaPlayback function in my uwp app. And this causes a media control appearing in preview thumbnail when mouse is hovering on taskbar button. According [microsoft learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/winenv-notification), it is called thumbnail toolbar. I wonder how to remove it from preview thumbnail. I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44752695/custom-ui-for-uwp-background-media-playback?rq=2) is same with mine but i try the answer, it doesn't work.[image: thumbnail toolbar]

Answer (score 1):

> how to remove thumbnail toolbar in UWP

I have to say that this is not possible. The thumbnail toolbar will show as long as you enabled the `backgroundMediaPlayback` capability in your app. Currently there is no API that could remove it unless you remove the `backgroundMediaPlayback` capability.